# Couldn't Use Shift+Alt+[←↑→↓] to Resize the Splits in Byobu

Tags: byobu

Enviroment: Linux Subsystem for Windows, Ubuntu 20.04.

What I want to achieve is to make my buttom split smaller.

[After using Shift+F2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYrL2.png)

And I just couldn't use the hotkeys `Shift+Alt+[←↑→↓]` to resize.

Along the way of finding a solution, I suddenly recall that I can use the `Shift+Alt` to change my language. So I went to the Windows settings to disable the hotkeys and restart my computer but nothing changed.

Whatsmore, I also tried to remap my hotkey for the resizing to Alt+up in Windows terminal setting. Still nothing changed.

I hope someone who has encountered the same problem and dealt with it could help nme out.